# Allow patch of symlinks

Tags: symlink, diff, patch

When I try to run a `patch` command with a patchfile against a link, patch gives me the error:

> File `path/to/file` is not a regular file -- refusing to patch

The following command produces this error when I have links to the files in question in my `staging` directory.

```
~> cd staging
~/staging> ls -l path/to/
lrwxrwxrwx 1 user users   15 Jan  1 00:00 file1 -> ../../../actual/path/file1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 user users   15 Jan  1 00:00 file2 -> ../../../actual/path/file2
~/staging> patch -p 1 -i ../patchfile
File path/to/file1 is not a regular file -- refusing to patch
2 out of 2 hunks ignored -- saving rejects to file path/to/file1.rej
File path/to/file2 is not a regular file -- refusing to patch
1 out of 1 hunk ignored -- saving rejects to file path/to/file2.rej
```

How can I tell `patch` not to ignore the symbolic links and patch them in-place as if they were normal files?

Comment: I can work around this by modifying the patch file itself, but that doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Perhaps **`--follow-symlinks`** option.

Comment: Not all implementations of `patch` have such an option (e. g. `patch` provided my Mac OS).

Comment: None of the POSIX compliant patch implementations have this option and if they would be anhanced, they did most likely implement `-H/-L/-P` that has been chosen by POSIX approx. 20 years ago for this purpose.

Answer (score 2):

GNU patch 2.7.1 ([since 2012](https://github.com/mirror/patch/commit/293415dbcf8c621c8aecb4347abd32fd60935a8b#diff-b7a4bb925cd071a69c66abbd5b57a4c3)) has a **`--follow-symlinks`** option:

> When looking for input files, follow symbolic links.   Replaces  the
>   symbolic  links,  instead  of modifying the files the symbolic links
>   point to.  Git-style patches to symbolic links will no longer apply.
>   This  option  exists  for backwards compatibility with previous versions of patch; its use is discouraged.

Comment: My version of `patch` (GNU patch 2.7.4 on cygwin) did not list this option in `patch --help`, but still supported it.

Comment: Good answer, but that it replaces the link, rather than modifies the target file makes it not work for my case. I updated the question slightly.